# Java setting JFrame visible gives exception when execute

Tags: java, static, nullpointerexception, jframe

Using JFrame as a static variable when I execute the main method this Null pointer Exception Occuers What is the Issue?

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36h4B.png)

Comment: Post the exception here, not in an image.

Comment: Short answer; `JFrame frame;` is the same as `JFrame frame = null;` **not** `JFrame frame = new JFrame();`. Thus your `frame` is `null` when you attempt to invoke `setVisible(true)`